# APIPA Address Showing for DNS & WINS Server 2012 r2

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

**Background**

I just finished setting up a Server 2012 r2 install.  It is the only server in the forest and I am only utilizing 1 NIC (it has two, but the second is disabled).  It is the DC and handles DNS and DHCP.  I have statics set for the IPv4 and DNS pointing to the server IP address.  I have IPv6 turned off as we aren't using it.  I do not have WINS installed as we have no need for it.

﻿﻿**The Problem**

﻿﻿Computers on the network are unable to navigate to webpages.  When I do a ipconfig /all on a networked PC I get the right DHCP server (the DC's IP), it is assigning leases properly, the Gateway is correct, and of course the ip is being assigned and within the correct range.

However, the IPv6 is displaying information, I'm not sure that anything should be there.  I have it unchecked on the server as well as the local PC.  And the big issue is that APIPA addresses are showing for DNS (one entry only as I didn't set up a alternate) and WINS.  I don't have WINS installed as a service on the server.

﻿**What I've Checked**

﻿I checked the records in DNS and can't find a reference to the APIPA address (I could be overlooking it, but I think I checked about every record I could find).  I am not using reverse look up so no records are present there.  I have forwarders set up to point to google dns (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4).

DCHP is showing the correct address and is started and authorized.

I've added the DNS server option to DHCP.

DNS is giving me these Information events: Event 4, 2, 769, and warning 4013. I believe these are all before I restarted the server.  I have no event log information after the restart.

﻿**Work Around**

﻿I can go to each PC and manually set the DNS server to the DC's IP and internet connectivity is restored.

Any pointers/help would be greatly appreciated!﻿

Comment: If your DHCP don't give IPv6 lease, can you validate that no router do distribute those lease ?

Comment: Is this actually causing you a problem?  And, do you mean it shows DNS servers of ::ffff:169.254.x.x?  Or do you mean link-local when you say APIPA?

Comment: Are you assigning an IPv4 address as the DNS server via DHCP to the clients? If not, you should be and it should be the IPv4 address of the server.

Comment: yagmoth555: Yes I can confirm that there are no other DHCP or DNS servers on the network.  A Cable Modem feeds into my Untangle Firewall, which feeds into a switch that feeds into the server and a patch panel.

Comment: joeqwerty: Yes, it is causing a problem.  To gain access to the internet I have to assign the DNS server's IP address to each computer on the network.  When it pulls the dns automatically, it pulls the 169.254.x.x APIPA address.
I do not have WINS installed on the server, but both DNS and WINS on the networked PC's show APIPA address when I do IPCONFIG /ALL

Comment: joeqwerty: Yes, I am assigning IPv4 address of the DNS server (which is housed on the only server on the network that also functions as the DC and performs DHCP).  IPv6 is turned off.  A second NIC is disabled.

Comment: Run a wireshark on a computer in problem. I suspect the DNS's option cant reach the PC if the lease come from your DC. The PC got the DHCP lease from DHCP-Helper ? (I ask as I seen modemcable) That would mean a firewall update too maybe if so.